# IntelliJ IDEA - Maven home directory setting resets for new projects

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, settings

I've just started using IntelliJ (I'm used to Eclipse) and I've come across something that really annoys me. Whether it's me or IntelliJ, I really want this fixed.

Every time I open a new project, the "Maven home directory" setting is reset and I therefore have to set this every time I open a project I haven't opened before.

Is there any way to set this setting permanently/globally?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.x or later:

[image: Settings for new projects]

[image: Welcome screen]

Older versions:

You can change it in the **Template Project Settings** so that all the new projects inherit this setting. You can access it from the `File` menu when the project is open or from the Welcome Screen: `Configure` | `Template Project` | `Settings`.

Comment: in the meantime the menu structure changed, so it's `File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Settings for New Projects...`

Answer (score 43):

In Intellij 2018.1:

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings...
```

[image]

Changing default settings will apply only to new projects.
Current project won't be affected.

Comment: It is still buggy in 15.0 Build #IU-143.381
You need to override "User settings file" and "Local repository" in order for it to work

Comment: I did the same thing with File -> Settings.. option. And it worked.

Answer (score 12):

In IntelliJ 2020.2 it's now directly

```
File -> New Projects Settings -> Settings for New Projects...
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Intellij 2018.2 its now under **File > Other Settings > Preference for New Projects**

Answer (score 0):

I would place your settings which are valid for all projects into maven/conf/settings.xml and not into the users home directory. Then set the environment variable M2_HOME to the maven folder. IntelliJ should then be able to auto-detect the maven installation. 
It does not look like it reads the settings.xml from the maven setup but it does use it, you don't have to overwrite the settings.xml in the idea settings dialog. just leave the default in place. But I think you need to set the M2_HOME variable in your system.